# How was Kakashi Hatake able to survive and become the next Hokage after losing his Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

I hardly read the manga. I watch the anime series, *Naruto: Shippuden*. In episode 424, Kakashi's Sharingan (previously Obito's Sharingan) is stolen by Madara. Then in episode 425, Naruto uses his new power and give Kakashi's old eye (as far I know and from my view, it is a normal eye).

Kakashi is the **Copy Ninja**. So how could Kakashi survive in the ninja world and become the next Hokage (I watched *The Last: Naruto the Movie*) with normal eyes? I'm curious because Kakashi's nickname was given because he used his Sharingan for copying others' jutsu. That was his technique. As I can remember in *Naruto* series, someone described Kakashi and told that the only jutsu he mastered by himself was the **Chidori**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very soon in anime,

> Obito will say that his gift for Kakashi was not full and will give him both Sharingans. He will manage to use Susanoo and save Naruto, Sasuke and Sakura from Kaguya's attack. I don't know why, but after war he has normal eyes, maybe he can deactivate Sharingan.

UPD.

I've read that chapter again and understood why he has normal eyes.

> Obito says that his present may expire but it's not completely useless.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG, its a disaster for an anime-only user. At least add the spoiler tags !

Comment: I see the answer is lay future in the anime :) thanks very much :) @Mihai Svet

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki, why would an anime-only user open this question?

Comment: @Kira-TheGod Interest would drive him to open this question. Why do you think spoiler tags exist in the site?

Comment: This answer would need an update, as the answer doesn't exactly reply to the question. It just readdresses the point that Kakashi doesnt have a sharingan after the Ninja war. Also, I am concerned about the fact that images from mangapanda are hosted here. I believe it is against the rules of the forum.

Answer (score 1):

A sword is only as sharp as the one who wields it. The sharingan was nothing but a ninja tool that Kakashi used. And he was good at it considering the fact that he was not a true Uchiha.

However, the tools a ninja uses is not the only criteria that would be considered while appointing him to a post of a kage. His diplomatic skills, his relation with the other villages, his services to the nation are some of the other (among a larger list) that needs to be considered.

In all these aspects, Kakashi has excelled. There can be no doubt on the fact that Kakashi was capable of fighting with and without the sharingan. His skills in strategy were at par with the best of the best. He had fair diplomatic skills, which we can assume from the fact that he had already been appointed for the post of hokage earlier (right after Danzo dies). He was a person of calm demeanor and not pragmatic. He weighed his options before making a decision and could think calmly in the face of adversity. All these does make him a strong contender for the position of Kage.

Tsunade was not only appointed as the hokage because she was a great medical ninja, but also because of her services in the endorsing the idea of the 4 man ninja team with a medic ninja included in each team.

Also, the sharingan that Kakashi had only allowed him to read the movements of his opponents in a precise manner. His ability to copy the jutsu was aided by the sharingan, but in the end he had to commit it to memory so that he could use it later on. Also he must have had excellent chakra control to read the hand signs of a jutsu once and copy it immediately. Also, he himself mentions while aiding naruto create his rasen shuriken, that he could use chakra of elements other than thunder. We have seen him use water style, earth style and fire style. So, his strength is not solely because of the sharingan. Like a tool, the sharingan helped his cause.

Answer (score 0):

Kakashi did not have his sharingan anymore. However, Kakashi did still have all the abilities he was shown copying and the last ability he copied in the naruto series is water dragon jutsu which was in the first series and it made it that far without copying another jutsu. I bet there are thousands of more jutsu that Kakashi has than the amount he's shown.