# Are there other Sharingan users who can copy other jutsu besides Kakashi?

Tags: naruto

After I have read this [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/how-was-kakashi-hatake-able-to-survive-and-become-the-next-hokage-after-losing-h), I remember that Kakashi's epithet is *Copy Ninja* because he has a Sharingan in his left eye that was given to him by Obito.

But I can't think of another Sharingan user who can also copy other jutsu. So, is that the only special technique that Kakashi's Sharingan had, or there's another Sharingan user who also can copy other jutsu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharingan literally means *Copy Wheel Eye*. The *Eye of Insight* and the *Eye of Hypnotism* are the two abilities of the Sharingan.

The Eye of Insight has different abilities in itself. One of the abilities, lets the user copy any jutsu and utilize with maximum achievable perfection.

> The user is able to copy almost any jutsu they see, memorising ninjutsu, genjutsu, and taijutsu with near-perfect accuracy. They can then either perform that jutsu or modify it to suit their needs, as when Sasuke Uchiha bases his Lion Combo on Rock Lee's Front Lotus. Again, Sharingan users need the prerequisite abilities before they can mimic a jutsu they have seen, and for that reason they cannot, for example, reproduce kekkei genkai abilities they do not have or nature transformations they haven't learned to perform.
>
> <sub>source: [Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sharingan)</sub>

Therefore, every Sharingan user is capable of using the Eye of Insight's ability of copying other jutsu, provided, their Sharingan are matured enough. It is not, therefore, exclusive to Kakashi. Every Sharingan user has this ability. Although, Kakashi is the only non-Uchiha able to perform it successfully.

Comment: besides Sasuke that can copy Rock Lee's Front Lotus, is there any other Sharingan users that can copy jutsu shown in the manga or anime? I can't remember about this

Comment: @JTR his brother can also do the same.

Comment: Itachi? when and what's kind of jutsu that copied by him?

Comment: Apparently anyone with a Sharingan can do it, it's just frightfully underused

Comment: @JTR: like the other comments suggest, all Sharingan users can copy jutsu. Kakashi and Sasuke are the ones with famous screentime though. Elite Uchiha (Madara, Itachi, Obito) are undoubtedly capable of using it too.